# python class variable works outside of class, not inside class

Tags: python, class

I have populated a couple of lists in my class.  Outside of the class, I can print both lists.  Inside the class, only one will show any elements.  I  don't see any spelling errors in my code, no syntax errors.  I'm completely lost...

At the bottom, when running "logging.info(self.fcNetwork_List)", it returns empty.  "logging.info(self.userName_list)" returns the list correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import getopt, sys, os, errno 
import logging 
import getpass    
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import time
from restapi import *

class OV_enclosure(object):
    ip_address = ""
    api_version = ""
    OV_username = ""
    OV_password = ""
    auth = ""
    userName_list = []
    fcNetwork_list = []

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def getAPIVersion(self):
        api_dict = getAPIVersion(self.ip_address)
        self.api_version = api_dict["currentVersion"]

    def getAuthID(self):
        auth_data = loginSessions(self.ip_address, self.api_version, self.OV_username, self.OV_password)

        try:
            self.auth = auth_data['sessionID']
        except KeyError:
            logging.error("Invalid key.  Verify your credentials in the loginSessions function")
            exit(1)

    def printClass(self):
        logging.debug("ip_address: %s" % self.ip_address)
        logging.debug("api_version: %s" % self.api_version)
        logging.debug("OV_username: %s" % self.OV_username)
        logging.debug("OV_password: %s" % self.OV_password)
        logging.debug("auth: %s" % self.auth)
        logging.debug("userName_list: %s" % self.userName_list)
        logging.info("self userName_List: ")
        logging.info(self.userName_list)
        logging.info("self fcNetwork_List: ")
        logging.info(self.fcNetwork_list)
        logging.debug("fcNetwork_list: %s" % self.fcNetwork_list)
```

Outside of class, both of these show a correctly populated list.

```
logging.info("printing enclosure username list")
logging.info(enclosure.userName_list)

logging.info("Printing enclosure fcNetworks list")
logging.info(enclosure.fcNetwork_List)


enclosure.printClass()
logging.info("Shutdown logging handles")
logging.shutdown()
print "\ndone"
```

I've excluded the code I feel is not important (entire class shown), but if you want all the code, I can do that.

Comment: How, and when, do you append values to `enclosure.fcNetwork_list`? Does "it returns empty" mean `None` or `[]`?

Comment: Where does fcNetwork_list get populated. Try `logging.info(isinstance(enclosure.fcNetwork_List, list))` to verify that it is an empty list that is printing.

Comment: Are you aware that the code you write will share your variables (especially the lists) amongst *all* instances of `OV_enclosure`?  This is nearly 100% not what you want, and probably the cause of your problem. Use the `__init__` method to populate your instance with variables. Unless you are really good at Python, class-level variables as you declare them are guaranteed to turn into bugs.

Comment: This is unrelated to your question but you might want to read up on [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is with improper use of class variable `userName_list` through `self` object.

If instance variable `self.userName_list` does not exist, getter would return `OV_enclosure.userName_list` but if you anywhere assign/define the instance version, it *shadows* the class one.

You would need explicitly access the class variables through class name qualifier.